# Can I set a variable value while awaiting on an async function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous

I have an async function `fileUpload()` which uploads files to a server and returns a promise when it is done. When a user wants to submit a different form, the `submitForm()` will `await fileUpload` before posting the form.

While it waits for `await fileUpload`, I would like to tell the user that the system is waiting for uploads to finish. Here is what I imagined (but obviously cannot work):

```
async fileUpload() {
   await Promise.all(
   // Does a for loop here and uploads all files
   )
}

async submitForm() {
  const FormBody = new FormData();

  await fileUpload; // I want to set this.IsUploading = true if awaiting. If not awaiting, then this.IsUploading = false; 

  this.$axios.post('/api', FormBody)
}
```

I use `await fileUpload` without the parenthesis because if I do `await fileUpload()` then it is invoking that function again. But how can I set `this.IsUploading` to `true` while awaiting for `fileUpload()` to finish and then set it to `false` if there is nothing more to wait for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just set the variable before and after the `await` call?

```
this.IsUploading = true;

await fileUpload;

this.IsUploading = false;
```

Comment: I tried this but the variable value never changed... it just stayed false. Are you sure this works?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some cases, that you can use.

1. I think this is the best and the most correct way, it'll call your function only once, maybe, the problem is in another thing?

```
async submitForm() {
  const FormBody = new FormData();

  await fileUpload();

  this.$axios.post('/api', FormBody)
}
```

2. You can make set your value to true and wait until `fileUpload()` returns something:

```
async submitForm() {
  const FormBody = new FormData();
  this.IsUploading = true;

  if (await fileUpload()) this.IsUploading = false;

  this.$axios.post('/api', FormBody)
}
```

3. Or just change it right away after getting respond from `fileUpload()`, as told Jack Bashford:

```
async submitForm() {
  const FormBody = new FormData();
  this.IsUploading = true;

  await fileUpload();
  this.IsUploading = false

  this.$axios.post('/api', FormBody)
}
```